# Trying to get the src path of image in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Im having issues getting the image src path for graph CMS using react & graphQL. The problem is the path is always returning null. I'm sure this has been asked many times but in order for me to learn I just need to see what I am doing wrong.

My query in graphQL is this:

```
query {
products {
  id
  name
  price
  description
  createdAt
  image {
    id
    url
  }
}
```

}

I always get all the other information but not the image src (which returns null).

my code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

const Product = (props) => {
  return (
      <div className="col-sm-4">
          <div className="card" style={{width: "18rem"}}>
            <img src={props.product.image.url} className="card-img-top" alt={props.product.name}/>
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{props.product.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-title">$ {props.product.price}</p>
              <p className="card-title">{props.product.description}</p>
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => props.addItem(props.product)}>Buy now</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}
export default Product;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have all other properties of product object, maybe image.url is really `null`. Put a break point, debug and see what you have inside props of Product component.

Comment: `src={props.product.image[0].url}` ?

Answer (score 5):

Marko Savic is right, it returns null

ANSWER: in GraphCMS you have to make sure you publish 'content' AND **'assets'**

[Published Assets in GraphCMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqFlf.png)

Comment: thank you,your first upvote from me ;)